# Swagger-ui.html is giving blank page

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

When I am trying to enable swagger in my spring boot application, it is showing blank page.
I am using url https://localhost:8080/context-path/swagger-ui/
I am able to get the JSON data for url https://localhost:8080/context-path/v2/api/docs
I am not getting where this going wrong for swagger ui can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Swagger config file

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
  
    @Bean
      public Docket api() { 
          return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
            .select()                                  
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
            .build();                                           
      }
  
}
```

I have added dependencies in pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1 </version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I have controller like this

```
@GetMapping public ResponseEntity<ProjectDto> getAllProjects() { ProjectDto projectDto = new ProjectDto(); try { List<ProjectDto> projectDtos = projectService.getAllProjects(); projectDto.setProjectDtos(projectDtos.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())); return new ResponseEntity<>(projectDto, HttpStatus.OK); } catch (ProjectNotFoundException exception) { LOGGER.info(exception.getMessage(), exception); projectDto.setErrorMsg(exception.getMessage()); return new ResponseEntity<>(projectDto, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); } catch (Exception exception) { LOGGER.info(exception.getMessage(), exception); projectDto.setErrorMsg("Something went wrong with projects"); return new ResponseEntity<>(projectDto, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); } }
```

Comment: Do you have any controllers defined? Could you share that?

Comment: Can you add that to the question? It is almost impossible to read this in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of time it is got worked for me,In my application I am using spring security so configurations were mismatched. That's why I got blank page.

I did following changes in Security config and JwtTokenAUthenticationFilter classes

1. Inside configure(HttpSecurity http), .antMatchers("/login","/","/project/jira/update","/leave",
2. "/v2/api-docs",

   "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll();
3. Inside configure(WebSecurity web), web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**")
   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");

JwtTokenAUthentication filter class

4. Inside JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter's doFilterInternal -> uri.indexOf("swagger") >= 0 || "/{context-path}/v2/api-docs".equals(uri)

or uri.contains("swagger")||uric.contains("/v2/api/docs")

here uri means HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

Comment: if you are extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the same Springfox version in all dependencies as follows?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Nevertheless and I know this does not solve your problem directly, but I would suggest you to consider moving to [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/). Springfox is so buggy at this point that is a pain to use. I've moved to `springdoc` 2 years ago because of its Spring WebFlux support and I am very happy about it. Additionally, it also supports Kotlin Coroutines, which I am not sure Springfox does.

If you decide to migrate, `springdoc` even has a [migration guide](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox).

Comment: I have tried using above versions but no luck. Okay will try that Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you are extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
public static final String[] SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST = new String[]{"/**/swagger-ui.html", "/**/webjars/**", "/**/swagger-resources", "/**/swagger-resources/**", "/**/v2/api-docs", "/**/configuration/ui", "/**/configuration/security", "/**/swagger-ui/**", "/**/v3/api-docs/**"};
// this one ignores under spring security
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
...
.antMatchers(SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
...
}
// this one ignores upon spring security(in my opinion, not the best option)
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST);
    super.configure(web);
}
```

In my case, my custom filter was causing problems, so you probably want just to review/refactor yours

Answer (score 0):

springfox-boot-starter ships with swagger-ui and swagger-2 [Reference](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/springfox/springfox-boot-starter/3.0.0/springfox-boot-starter-3.0.0.pom)

Could you please try removing the explicitly added dependencies and access
**/swagger-ui/** or /**swagger-ui/index.html**

Answer (score 0):

My solution was that request to swagger-ui was intercepted by a custom filter that was checking header for specific key,value.
 Check your filters your filter may be intercepting your request and returning nothing leading to empty swagger ui page

Answer (score 0):

We migrate spring 3.1.0 to 3.1.2 and had a colateral effect,

This approach was working well in Spring boot 3.1.0

```
...
.requestMatchers("/v3/**","/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
...
```

But in version 3.1.2 that approach got Blank screen on swagger uri /swagger-ui

```
...
.requestMatchers("/v3/**","/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
...
```

To correct It, I used the constructor of AntPathRequestMatcher with a single parameter

```
...
.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/**")).permitAll()
.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring boot 3(3.1.2 in my case) with

```
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
```

please make sure permit openapi v3 public endpoint like this

```java
new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**","GET"),
new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**","GET"),
new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui.html","GET")
```

and url below will work success

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
```