# Swagger-ui blank white screen in newer spring boot version (2.4.0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have been using Swagger-ui for almost 3 years. But funny fact is I couldn't resolve a simple issue. Recently, I am using newer version of Spring boot namely 2.4.0 or newer version.

Main issue is whether openAPI or swagger ui couldn't generate. I tried both but failed.

Swagger-ui whole white screen without any rendered element. Looks like that:
[image: Screenshot]

What should I do? guys please save my day!

Pom.xml looks like:

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

Comment: Are there any log in the chrome console or in your app ?

Comment: @Aserre I don't have any log.

Comment: Maybe another avenue worth exploring : when I add `@EnableSwagger2` on my main class, the url generated for the swagger is `https://my-app.com/swagger-ui.html`

Comment: Possibly related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320464/swagger-ui-html-is-giving-blank-page